# CodeIgniter function to clear session

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

If i uncomment this code, i get blank page at site. If i comment this, site works.
Here is my exit code (auth by sessions):

```
    function exit($action='') {
    if ($action == "true") {
        echo "Exit.";
        return;
    }
    $login = $this->session->userdata('username');
    if ($login == NULL) {
        redirect('/blog/login/', 'location', '301');
    }
    $array_itmes = array('username' => "$login");
    $this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
    redirect('/blog/exit/true/', 'location', '301');}
```

after normal login:

```
    $newdata = array('username' => "$name");
    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

in other actions i using:

```
    $login = $this->session->userdata('username');
    if ($login !== NULL) {
        echo $login;
    }
```

and I get my username. where is an error in first code? i`m from Russia, so sorry for bad English.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you 100% which is why I can't answer your question, but defining a method called 'exit' might be problematic, since it's a reserved word for PHP. Try renaming it and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just replace it with `$this->session->sess_destroy();`

Answer (score 4):

```
$array_val = array('userid' => '','username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_val);
```

This is remove individual session details.

Answer (score 2):

Anton's answer will destroy whole session at once. If you would want to delete entire session data use this like Anton said,

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

But if you would want to only destroy specific user data use below,

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('user_name');
```

Hope this helps, thanks!!

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

To clear the current session (for example, during a logout), you may simply use either PHP’s `session_destroy()` function or the `sess_destroy()` method. Both will work in exactly the same way:

```
session_destroy();

// or

$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use
`session()->destroy();`

it clears the session buffer so you get the logging out effect.